# How to generate really minimalistic model interfaces with openapi-generator using typescript-fetch?

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm experimenting with `openapi-generator` and its `typescript-fetch` generator implementation. Overall the generator is good, but in my honest opinion it does a bit too much.

I can configure the `openapi-generator` to generate only models, which would be my final goal. However, `typescript-fetch` generator insists generating serialization and deserialization helper functions which import some `exists` and `map` from `../runtime`. But while only models are getting generated, the `../runtime` is of course missing. In my case I totally don't need these (de)serializer helpers and I would like to omit them completely. I don't see any option currently to do so.

```
ExampleModel.ts

// This line does not compile in model-only mode
import { exists, mapValues } from '../runtime';

/**
 * 
 * @export
 * @interface ExampleModel 
 */
export interface ExampleModel {
    /**
     * 
     * @type {number}
     * @memberof ExampleModel 
     */
    someNumber?: number;
}

// These functions are useless for me and do only trouble

export function ExampleModelFromJSON(json: any): AuthenticateUserCommand {
    return ExampleModelFromJSONTyped(json, false);
}

export function ExampleModelFromJSONTyped(json: any, ignoreDiscriminator: boolean): ExampleModel {
    if ((json === undefined) || (json === null)) {
        return json;
    }
    return {
        
        'someNumber': !exists(json, 'someNumber') ? undefined : json['someNumber'],
    };
}

export function ExampleModelToJSON(value?: ExampleModel | null): any {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (value === null) {
        return null;
    }
    return {
        
        'someNumber': value.someNumber
    };
}
```

Is there a way to generate a really minimalistic model (typescript interfaces)? Could I customize the mustache templates somehow in the scope of our project? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can use [ng-openapi-gen](https://github.com/cyclosproject/ng-openapi-gen). I love this tool, but it is for an angular project. But you could delete the other files afterwards. Not the prettiest solution of course.

Comment: If you managed to come up with a solution, please would you mind posting here? I have the same problem.